# Release Management 2015 Deploy zip file to a Linux server and run a SH file on the Linux server

Tags: linux, deployment, release-management, ms-release-management, dsc

I'm investigating if I can deploy a zip file and then run the SH file on the Linux server using Microsoft Release Manager 2015.

I've followed the link from http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-10-52-77-91/DSC-deployment-in-RM.pdf but I don't want to run an agent on the Linux box.

The following article works but its outside RM. http://blogs.technet.com/b/privatecloud/archive/2014/05/19/powershell-dsc-for-linux-step-by-step.aspx#pi169501=2

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The only out-of-the-box supported mechanism is to use Chef.

DSC for Linux didn't work in RM 2013. I don't know if RM 2015 changed the story or not, but I would expect that it did not. **Note:** DSC for Windows worked fine.

The only option I've ever seen that works for Linux is to use an agent-based deployment. The architecture is like this:

- Choose a Windows machine to act as a "springboard" that will actually execute the deployment
- Create a custom tool for PuTTY (specifically, PLink/PSFTP)
- Use the custom tool to invoke the appropriate SSH tools to copy the deployment artifacts (binaries/scripts) to the Linux machine and execute the scripts

The new RM Service in VSTS (and in on-premise TFS 2015 later this year) will make for a much smoother experience, as it has better support for non-Windows environments.